# XCODE 4.2 not showing the line of crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

I just updated to XCODE 4.2. Unlike the previous version where when my app crash it would show me the line of code where it crashed, it shows me this in console:

```
2011-10-20 08:50:47.342 PipeTracker[19467:15503] -[Job objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8085500
2011-10-20 08:50:47.343 PipeTracker[19467:15503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Job objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8085500'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ca1052 0x1e32d0a 0x1ca2ced 0x1c07f00 0x1c07ce2 0x690a 0x22071d 0x220952 0xaa886d 0x1c75966 0x1c75407 0x1bd87c0 0x1bd7db4 0x1bd7ccb 0x1b8a879 0x1b8a93e 0x190a9b 0x2d1d 0x2c95)
```

Is there a setting i need to change?
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you lose your Exception breakpoint? Go to the Breakpoints navigator, click the + button, and add an Exception breakpoint.

Comment: Nice. This option is so underrated. Everyone should know about it. Thanks!